# How do I add a small dotted line in the legend of a Highcharts graph?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to get it to look like this where the in the legend, there is a small dotted line followed the words
[image]

I can get the words just fine like this
[image]

,but I can't get the little dotted line even though I have no issue getting the text. The problem is that when I try to do addPlotLine function, but the problem is that the little dotted line I want is in the legend and the addPlotLine function can only be called on Axis. How do I add the little "-------" next to the text "Trend Line Average" like in the first graph which is my UI mock?

Comment: Hi, just to be sure - is it a legend or the Axes title?

Comment: @magdalena That text is just rendered with the renderer.text function. It's not a property of legend or Axis Title.

Comment: What about the rendering of the line as well? Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hgsfwnu7/

Comment: @magdalena Thanks, that totally works! One last thing that I'm struggling with is the styling I try adding "style:'color:#666666;'" to the attr so that it looks like this         chart.customLine = chart.renderer.path(['M', plotLeft - 50, chart.plotHeight + plotTop + 44, plotLeft - 5, chart.plotHeight + plotTop + 44])
          .attr({
          style:'color:red;',
            'stroke-dasharray': 2,
            'stroke-width': 1,
            stroke: '#4572A7'
          })
          .add(); But that doesn't change the dotted line so that it's red. Any help you can give me with that?

Comment: That's great to hear! For the path, the color is changed through the property `stroke`, so in that case, you need to only change; `stroke: 'red'`